# How to disable delay to detect single/double tap on List component to improve performance in Sencha Touch 2.2

Tags: performance, events, listview, sencha-touch-2

I am using a list component and there seems to be a very noticeable delay when tapping a list item to open the next view. My understanding is that it is waiting to detect whether the tap is a single tap or a double tap. In the case of my app, all taps will always be single taps as there is no double tap action. Is there a way to disable this delay or prevent it so that the performance with which the app reacts to tap events is improved?

Answer (score 0):

I use FastClick ([Official Page](http://labs.ft.com/articles/ft-fastclick/)) ([GitHub](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)). You end up having to add a block of about 500 lines of code to your app, which of course isn't ideal, but it works quite well and is super easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use double taps in your app, then add this code to your app.js:

```
eventPublishers: {
    touchGesture: {
        recognizers: {
            doubleTap: null,
        }
    }
},
```

This will prevent app/touch/src/event/recognizer/DoubleTap.js from loading. The maxDuration of 300 ms is set there.